# Why FREETEXTTABLE scan entire table if there is a fulltext index available?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

There is a simple table of cities

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cities](
    [id] [numeric](6, 0) NOT NULL,
    [cityname] [varchar](48) NOT NULL,
)
```

and a full-text catalog which index not only names of cities:

The table has 6259 rows.

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE([cities],[cityname],
N'Hello, I am looking for cities inside this text,
my house is not -far from London  PJ-')
```

The results contains 11 rows and the query execution takes about 1-2 seconds.
According to execution plan, 6092 rows were scanned in the index.

Why so many rows are scanned if there is index?

[image: execution plan]

I Use SQL Server 2012.

UPDATE:

There is no special index on table cities. The only index from object explorer looks like:

```
Create TABLE [dbo].[cities] ADD  CONSTRAINT [xpkruianobec] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: show the index definition

Comment: How to get the index definition? Script catalog as index does not work for the fulltext index. It shows only CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ftRealty]WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF without table and column definition.

Comment: It should be under Indexes in the object explorer.  You cannot use FREETEXTTABLE without a Full Text Index.

Comment: Updated. So Do I need to add index to the cities table? Adn then set this index in the fulltext catalog?

Comment: There is no ID in FREETEXTTABLE, there two columns, Rank and Key. If I just select a Key, execution plan is same.

Comment: Sorry, its been a while since i played with full text.  The index under the index folders is not the correct one.  Right click on the table name in the object explorer, highlight full text index, then click properties.  that will show the columns in the full text index.

Comment: I'd guess that your table has that many records in total and SQL Server has decided that it's easier to scan full table rather than seek through clustered index based on FULLTEXT search results.